# Java Tree isSorted

Tags: java, recursion, tree

For school I must write a own tree class in Java. If have problems too write a function called idSorted, who checks if the tree is sorted in in-order. It must be recursive and I should use the getMin and getMax methods. I know that I check this like that:

```
getLeft().getMax() <= this.getValue() && this.getRight().getMin();
```

But I have no idea to get that recursive. Here is the class:

```
class  Tree {

    private int value;
    private Tree left;
    private Tree right;

    public Tree(int i){
        this.value = i;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(int s){
        this.value = s;
    }

    public Tree getLeft(){
        return this.left;
    }

    public void setLeft(Tree l){
        this.left = l;
    }

    public Tree getRight(){
        return this.right;
    }

    public void setRight(Tree r){
        this.right = r;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ( this . getLeft () == null ? "" : this . getLeft (). toString () + ", ")
        + this . getValue () +
        ( this . getRight () == null ? "" : ", " + this . getRight (). toString ());
    }

    public Tree copy(){
        Tree  res = new  Tree(this.getValue ());
        res.setLeft(this.getLeft () == null ? null : this.getLeft (). copy ());
        res.setRight(this.getRight () == null ? null : this.getRight (). copy ());
        return  res;
    }

    public int getMin(){
        if (this.getLeft () == null) {
            return  this.getValue ();
        } else {
            return  this.getLeft (). getMin ();
        }
    }

    public int getMax(){
        if (this.getRight () == null) {
            return  this.getValue ();
        } else {
            return  this.getLeft (). getMax ();
        }
    }

    public boolean isSort(){
        //todo

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues:

1. The check condition you have mentioned is not correct.
2. Change the name of the class as Node which is more proper.
3. In case you do not want a container [Tree] class, you should have a property root
4. Use the root value (an instance of your node class which currently named as Tree) in isShort() method to check the condition and then call isShort() on left and right nodes if present (that is not null).

As you are learning - I left coding part as an exercise for you.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried something, hope thats right

```
public boolean isSorted(){
    if(this.getvalue()<getMin()||this.getvalue()>getMax()){
        return false;
    }
    //Schaut im linken Teil
    boolean linksrichtig =false;
    //gibt es nen linken Unterbaum
    if(this.getleft()!=null){
        //linker unterbaum kleiner?
        if(this.getleft().getvalue()<this.getvalue()){
            //rekursiv weiterschauen richtung links
            linksrichtig = isSorted();
        }else{
            //wenn größer dann falsch
            linksrichtig = false;
        }
    }else{
        //wenn links nichts exestiert dann richtig
        linksrichtig = true;
    }
    //Schaut im rechten Teil
    boolean rechtsrichtig =false;
    //gibt es nen rechten Unterbaum
    if(this.getright()!=null){
        //rechter unterbaum größer oder gleich?
        if(this.getright().getvalue()>=this.getvalue()){
            //rekursiv weiterschauen richtung rechts
            rechtsrichtig = isSorted();
        }else{
            //wenn kleiner dann falsch
            rechtsrichtig = false;
        }
    }else{
        //wenn rechts nichts exestiert dann richtig
        rechtsrichtig = true;
    }
    return (rechtsrichtig&&linksrichtig);
}
```